# How to treat the arguments of a macro as literal or verbatim text?

Tags: macros, verbatim

I'm working on a package that allows Python code to be entered within certain commands and environments, saves the Python code to external files and executes it, and brings back the results via `\input`.  Similar to SympyTeX and SageTeX, but with additional features.

As a trivial example, `\pylab{print 1+1}` would save the text string `print 1+1` to a file, Python executes this file to obtain `2` and saves this in a second file, and this second file is brought back into the original document with `\input`.

This is a minimal example.  (It will give errors after the first run, before Python is run to create infile.tex.)

```
\newcommand{\pylab}[1]{
    \newwrite\outputstream
    \immediate\openout\outputstream=outfile.py
    \immediate\write\outputstream{#1}
    \immediate\closeout\outputstream
    \input{infile.tex}
}
```

The problem is that in more complex cases, the argument for `\pylab` could contain special characters, for example `\pylab{print 3%2}` (modulus operator).  What's the best way to deal with this?  Ideally, my command would act like `\verb`, so that it would take anything but * as the switch, so as to be able to work around almost any special code characters.  I've been reading about verbatim, catcodes, `\gdef`, etc., but I haven't been able to get anywhere with those yet.

SympyTeX and SageTeX use

```
\catcode`\%=12
\newcommand{\percent}{%}
\catcode`\%=14
```

to define a replacement for %, but I want to avoid that route if possible since it means that I can't just directly paste in valid Python code.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if it is going to help you, but perhaps you would like to have a look at [python.sty](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/oct/24/embedding-python-latex/). You may find the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/pmav99/python.sty) or at the internet archives.

Comment: About your code example: `\newwrite\outputstream` must be outside of `\pylab` and only executed once.
And the percent character is already defined as `\@percentchar`.

Comment: checkout the bashful package; it does  roughly what you want, but for bash

Comment: See also: [Can you interpret macro parameters as verbatim? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256983/can-you-interpret-macro-parameters-as-verbatim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the argument verbatim using the follow technique. However this keeps `{` and `}` normal so they need to be matched inside the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\@pyout
\newcommand{\pylab}{%
    \begingroup
    % deactivate special characters
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    % change '{' and '}' back to normal
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    \@pylab
}
\def\@pylab#1{%
    \endgroup
    \immediate\openout\@pyout=\jobname.py
    \immediate\write\@pyout{#1}%
    \immediate\closeout\@pyout
    \immediate\write18{python \jobname.py > \jobname-py.tex}%
    \input{\jobname-py}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\pylab{print 3%2}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want the behavior of `\verb` use the following code which is inspired by the actual `\verb` code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newwrite\@pyout

\newcommand{\pylab}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \verb@eol@error
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \catcode`#1\active
    \lccode`\~`#1%
    \lowercase{\def\@@pylab##1~}{\endgroup\@pylab{##1}}%
    \@@pylab
}

\def\@pylab#1{%
    \immediate\openout\@pyout=\jobname.py
    \immediate\write\@pyout{#1}%
    \immediate\closeout\@pyout
    \immediate\write18{python \jobname.py > \jobname-py.tex}%
    \input{\jobname-py}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pylab|print 3%2|

\end{document}
```

#### Update:

With the new version 2011/07/23 of my `newverbs` package you can simplify the `\pylab` macro to `\newcommand{\pylab}{\begingroup\Collectverb{\@pylab}}`.

Comment: It's possible to avoid writing the `\jobname-py.tex` file by changing the two lines before the final brace into `\@@input|"python \jobname.py"` (it still requires shell-escape enabled).

Comment: Thanks!  The first solution does everything I wanted--seems to handle everything I've thrown at it, and since I'm dealing with code, matched braces isn't an issue.