# macro to showcase newly defined macros

Tags: macros, verbatim

I have the following MWE which takes an argument and prints it verbatim. I have obtained the code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19314/21372) answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myverb}{%
    \begingroup
    % deactivate special characters
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    % change '{' and '}' back to normal
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    \@myverb%
}
\def\@myverb#1{%
    \endgroup%
    \texttt{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\myverb{$\alpha$}
\end{document}
```

yields `$\alpha$` on the page.

I want to define a macro `\showcase` which will print the code that was used for the text, and the evaluation of that code, namely

```
\newcommand\showcase[1]{\myverb{#1} #1}
\showcase{$\alpha$}
```

I expected this to print

```
$\alpha$ <actual-letter-alpha>
```

but instead it prints

```
<actual-letter-alpha> <actual-letter-alpha>
```

because the argument is expanded before it is taken by `\myverb` (I think).

What should I do to make the macro behave the way I want?

**Note:** I want to use this macro either inside a table or minipages, so that I can showcase the macros I have defined. So I need to be able to play with it, like put the column delimiter `&` between, or separate them into two minipage environments.

Comment: `\newcommand\showcase[1]{\texttt{\meaning#1} #1}}`

Comment: The argument is not expanded, but catcode changes have no affect on tokens (which is why you can not use `\verb` in a macro argument`) so your definition is just `\texttt{#1}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, I also noticed curly braces are not printed. How can I achieve this then?

Comment: curly braces should be printed by \meaning in texttt ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant in the one I defined, `\myverb`.

Comment: a better heading might be "macro to print definition code verbatim".  your original title describes *why* you want to do something, but not *what* you want to do.

Comment: sorry that one really isn't what you want (or fixable), the first thing is to use `\meaning`, then you don't have a problem with `{}` If you don't like eh prefix `\meaning` adds you can remove it (see for example the definition of verb in `tabularx`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\meaning`, something like

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\foo#1>{}

\newcommand\showcase[1]{%
\def\tmp{#1}%
\texttt{\expandafter\foo\meaning\tmp} #1}

\begin{document}

\showcase{$\alpha$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting a space after `\alpha`. What could be the reason? I'm getting spaces after macros in general.

Comment: @nrs tex has _no idea_ whether you entered `$\alpha$` or `$\alpha          $`  that information just isn't recorded. It always puts a space out so that if you entered `$\alpha a$` it shows `$\alpha a$` not `$\alphaa$`

Comment: @nrs an alternative would be to use `\verb|$\alpha$| $alpha$`

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Although I still wonder whether there is a way to make it verbatim and evaluate it at the same time? Is it not possible? Because it would be much better if I could also adjust the spaces.

Comment: You could read it verbatim and then use `\scantokens` but scantokens can bite, I'd use the one in the answer or the one in the comments:-)